# Forward Sound Through to Headphone port--Mac

Tags: mac, audio, merge, audio-output

I have a Mac Mini which is connected to its sound output through the sound output port. I was wondering whether I can have the audio output from another computer into the Mac's sound in port and have it merged with the output going to the headphone port. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LineIn by Rogue Amoeba](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) does just that.